# What is the purpose of sys.exc_info()?

Tags: python, exception, cpython

I would like to understand the difference between:

```
try:
    raise Exception("wat")
except Exception:
    extype, exc, tb = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_exception(extype, exc, tb)
```

and:

```
try:
    raise Exception("wat")
except Exception as exc:
    extype = type(exc)
    tb = exc.__traceback__
    traceback.print_exception(extype, exc, tb)
```

Is there any case where `type(exc)` and `exc.__traceback__` are different from the values returned by `sys.exc_info()`? If not, when should I prefer one over the other? When I tested this (Python 3.7), the objects returned are referentially identical.

Looking at the implementation of `exc_info()` in CPython, the first return value (the exception type) appears to be obtained by calling [PyExceptionInstance_Class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fee552669f21ca294f57fe0df826945edc779090/Python/ceval.c#L4258), which is exactly the same as `type(exc)`. However, I was unable to find how the traceback is set.

(FWIW I am aware of the `traceback.print_exc()` shorthand, that is irrelevant to this question)

Comment: `sys.exc_info()` only works with the current exception, you can use the other operations on any exception.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that, I guess my question is more "Why does `exc_info` exist given that we can obtain the same values directly from the exception object?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__traceback__` attribute is available only since Python 3.0, so if you're looking to make your code compatible with Python 2 you should use `sys.exc_info()` instead; otherwise, per [PEP-3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#motivation), the introduction of the `__traceback__` attribute is indeed meant to fully replace `sys.exc_info()`, and possibly deprecate it:

> In today's Python implementation, exceptions are composed of three
>   parts: the type, the value, and the traceback. The `sys` module, exposes
>   the current exception in three parallel variables, `exc_type`,
>   `exc_value`, and `exc_traceback`, the `sys.exc_info()` function returns a
>   tuple of these three parts, and the raise statement has a
>   three-argument form accepting these three parts. Manipulating
>   exceptions often requires passing these three things in parallel,
>   which can be tedious and error-prone. Additionally, the except
>   statement can only provide access to the value, not the traceback.
>   Adding the `__traceback__` attribute to exception values makes all the
>   exception information accessible from a single place.

Comment: Ahhh I see, so `exc_info` came first, and `__traceback__` was added later. I was under the impression `__traceback__` has always existed. I'm still not sure why they felt the need to return the type of the exception object, but at least this explains why we have `exc_info`. Thanks!

Comment: @andrew-sun Probably because in the earlier versions of Python 2, built-in exceptions were *strings*,  not classes, and `raise` in Python 2 was able to take a tuple like the one that `sys.exc_info` returns, but could _not_ correctly take a tuple of just exception value and traceback, without a type in front. Basically, in early enough Python 2 versions, you couldn't do `raise ValueError('foo')`, because `ValueError` was just a string constant, but you *could* do `raise ValueError, 'foo'` (or `raise ValueError, 'foo', traceback`). So `sys.exc_info` matches that.

Comment: @andrew-sun `sys.exc_info` was also a thread-safe replacement for all three of `sys.exc_type`, `sys.exc_value`, and `sys.exc_traceback`. So they realized those global variables were starting to be a problem now that people were using threads in Python more, and at that point they had the choice of providing one interface or multiple. And I suspect the stuff in my prior comment influenced the choice to go for one interface, but I could also see the rationale being just focused on "why add multiple functions when you can just put all three pieces of information in one?"